# How would I make these curved indents in this water bottle? Picture in description.

Tags: modeling

I'm relatively new. I know how to make a water bottle starting with a circle and extruding upwards while using a combo of extrude and scaling to make indents, but how would I do something like this? I'm still trying to wrap my head around some of the photos I see out there. This is such an incredible program. Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: I know how to do this, I should have time to post an answer tonight a little later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by making the main outline of your bottle. Once you have that, hover over the section you want to add the inset to and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Use the scroll wheel to select exactly how many you want.

[image: adding loopcuts]

Now use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to switch to edge select mode. Holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, right click on the newly added loop-cuts. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel and roll the scroll wheel one click to add another loop cut in the middle.

[image: Beveling]

Now select the inner loop-cut on each of those rings. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (period) to change to the *Individual Origins* pivot point. Scale the selection down as desired.

[image: Scaling]

Now go into orthographic mode, and press <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> and select the center vertices as shown. Move them up as desired. Go ahead and press <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> and do the same thing. Enable a Subdivision Modifier, and bevel the edges using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

[image]

---

## Final result:

[image: result]

Comment: If something is unclear, let me know

Comment: Wow I didn't think I would get an answer thank you SO much. Really. This community is really easing the initial learning curve of this program. This technique is going to help me in many occasions.

Comment: I am actually having a problem. I have selected the middle loop cuts, but when I press control+period nothing happens.

Comment: Acutally I figured it out. You press and CTRL+. and then you scale it.