# How can I achieve this model

Tags: modeling

I just started learning Blender. How can I achieve that model, namely the expanded dents on the cap?

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot to upload your image......

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello @Christopher Bennett I have added a pic.

Comment: 4 pics actually... lol

Comment: One simple option is to use a simple array of rectangles in a circular way. [Like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/how-to-make-a-circular-array-using-offset-object-as-center)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134710/how-do-i-make-this-twisted-surface-on-a-bottle

Comment: Duarte, thanks the link was really helpful.

Comment: Emir.. thanks a lot. I love it here already