# I want to Model this bottle but how do i make the groove on its surface?

Tags: modeling, mesh, glass

[image]

How do i model this bottle and how to give the liquid inside similiar color.

Comment: Will you render it with Cycles (or Eevee)?

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52488/how-can-i-model-indentations-on-a-surface/52515#52515 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35791/how-would-i-make-these-curved-indents-in-this-water-bottle-picture-in-descripti https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134710/how-do-i-make-this-twisted-surface-on-a-bottle

Answer (score 1):

You can create the wave pattern, duplicate, cut in half:

[image]

Fill the gaps:

[image]

Use a *Simple Deform/Bend* mode in order to bend:

[image]