# Draw some Groove on Object

Tags: modeling, modifiers, knife-tool

I'm designing a Sause Bottle In blender Lately. But I just Faced a Roadblock.
As you can see in Reference Photos Below, there is some Grooves on The Top of The Bottle And I just Cant Pull it off!

[image]

[image]

I Tried Using Knife Tool Which Took me 20 minutes To Create Only One Out Of 12. So I Found Out This is Not The Right Way. So I Tried To Make Something Looking Like The Groove Itself To Use Boolean On it.

Here is The Result From The Second Way That I Tried (Boolean Modifier):

[image]
[image]

Which Caused This Disaster On Quantity of Vertices And Edges In Just A Really Narrow Area!!
So is There Any Other Way Or Any Hint That Yall Could Give me?

Comment: i would try it with sculpting...

Comment: You don't need so many faces in my opinion. You can check my answer here, except you don't need to twist it at the end: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134710/how-do-i-make-this-twisted-surface-on-a-bottle/134771#134771

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55635/making-rounded-dips-in-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134710/how-do-i-make-this-twisted-surface-on-a-bottle https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52488/how-can-i-model-indentations-on-a-surface https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35791/how-would-i-make-these-curved-indents-in-this-water-bottle-picture-in-descripti